# Problema com botão dropdown no Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia pessoal, tudo bem?

Estou fazendo alguns testes com o Bootstrap e estou com problema para criar um botão dropdown, copiei o código da documentação para testar, mas nada funciona. Segue aqui o projeto que estou testando

https://codepen.io/filipefalco/pen/zYooVoO?editors=1000

Alguém sabe dizer o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Você tem que importar os arquivos CSS do Bootstrap....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">     
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O seu funcionou mano, mas utilizando a versão 5 do bootstrap o dropdown não abriu. Poderia ser algum problema com esta versão? Ou eu que estou errando em algo?

Comment: Achei o problema aqui, houve uma alteração entre as versões. Na versão 5, o atributo "data-toggle" vira "data-bs-toggle"

Comment: Show de bola, que bom que deu certo

Comment: Segue o link da documentação: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/